# Remapping Econtroller in Rails.vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I started using Vim to do my editing in Ruby on Rails, so I installed the Rails.vim plugin.  I really like this plugin, but I have a few issues with it:

1. I have to type *:Econtroller Controller* to edit a controller. The same for models (:Emodel Model), etc.  If I had a controller named people, it would be much easier to type *:ec People* and press enter.  **This would save me 9 characters**, not counting every time I have to hit the shift key to capitalize the E!
2. I don't feel that I should have to capitalize the class name when opening the file as described in bullet #1. For example, if I do want to edit the People controller, I have to press the shift key before I even start to type the name of the class.  Then, I type fast enough that I regularly hold down shift too long and *People* becomes *PEople*, then Rails.vim RENAMES the file to PEople!

If you have any solutions or suggestions, please let me know.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me I always type `:Ec<tab>` or `:Emo<tab>` and that's it.. what do you get when you do that ? and for the class names, type as much as u like all in small letter and underscores then `<tab>` it will cycle as you like, just make sure to use small letters, because if you type a wrong cap letter it won't fix it, but small letters gets capped fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:cabbrev` to make exactly the shortcut you're asking for:

```
:cabbrev ec Econtroller
```

This way, when typing `ec<space>`, this will expand to `Econtroller<space>` anywhere on the command line. See `:help abbreviations` for more details.

As for capitalization, I don't actually think you need to capitalize the controller. At least on my installation of rails.vim, `:Econtroller users` works just fine to get me to the `UsersController`. Maybe you should update your rails.vim plugin?